# How to break data into two different screens in android

Tags: java, android

i am trying to integrate horizontal flip effect for data,so that in the first screen there will be 20 lines and in the second screen there will be continuation of the first screen data after 20 lines so on...Please help me..

Comment: `ViewFlipper` would do what you want. Put 20 lines on one side, then flip to the next set, etc

Comment: Can you post example source for that....those data is coming from server

Answer (score 1):

You need to use fragments to that. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROfJkJqqUYY), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQtF_mD9coo) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbyCmiRSRzk) is how.